# Contrail as an install option in Landscape Openstack Auto Pilot

Tags: openstack, openstack-autopilot

Is there an ETA when this functionality will be available in the UI? Also, is there a beta/testing branch open to public for Openstack Auto pilot?

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had better news, but the answer to both questions is "no"